Structure of hydroquinone-SO2 clathrate
I've been looking all over the internet for the structure of hydroquinone-SO2 clathrate, but couldn't find anything. I found structures of hydroquinone clathrates with different guest molecules, but I need exactly this one. Where can I look to find it?

I don't recall any papers I've read ever describing the structure specifically—in any case, I don't think it would be too different from the normal hexameric clathrate structures with the guest in the middle. Similar enough to this image. What is special about this one that you require it?

@Sonder:  Sure, structure is changed according to  nature of guest and reaction conditions. See my answer below for some insight.


Ref.: Supramolecular Chemistry by Jonathan W. Steed and Jerry L. Atwood, John Wiley & Sons, 2022
The formula is described by an encirclement:

Ref.: Sulfur Dioxide: Applications in Foods, Beverages, and Pharmaceuticals by Louis C. Schroeter, Elsevier, 2013
More on the preparation of the compound, refer to Page 6 of the book "Development of Krypton-85 Clathrate Analytical Techniques to Measure Oxidation-reduction Products in the Liquid State by George J. Rotariu, USAEC, 1962"

Nilay Ghosh has given enough information to fulfil GP's requirement in this question. Thus, I'm including some important additional information for other viewers who are interested on the subject.
According to recent review of Ref. 1:

Hydroquinone exists in four forms in the solid state, labelled $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, and $\delta$, of which only the $\beta$-form forms significant clathrates (the $\alpha$-form has small pores that can includes small linear guests such as $\ce{CO2}$). The $\gamma$-phase is closed-packed, while the $\delta$-phase is a high pressure phase of an unknown structure.$^{67}$ $\beta$-Hydroxyquinone clathrates have the general formula $\ce{3C6H4(OH)2.xG}$, where $\ce{G}$ is the guest species and $x$ is a site occupancy factor depending on reaction conditions.

The schematic diagram showing the (a) hydroquinone cage structure and (b) structure of the $\beta$-hydroquinone lattice cavity with methylisocyanide $(\ce{CH3N#C})$ guest are showing in the reference 1 as an example:

The Ref. 1 further states that:

For full occupancy of every cage, $x = 1$, but for many guest species, $x$ may be less than $1$ (e.g. $\ce{G = Xe}, \ x = 0.866$; $\ce{G = H2S}, \ x = 0.874$) and a stable clathrate still results. The six-membered ring and cavity dimensions are capable of significant distortion in response to guest dimensions. Thus, small spherical guests such as $\ce{Xe}$ and $\ce{H2S}$ form high symmetry type I (space group $R\bar3$) cages. With methanol, $\ce{SO2}$, and $\ce{HCl}$, the symmetry is lowered to $R3$ (no longer centrosymmetric), giving a type II clathrate in which the cage length is increased to accommodate the longer guest.

The example given in above image with $\ce{CH3N#C}$ guest is an example of a type III clathrate, in which three different guest orientations are observed (symmetry $P3$). It is also interesting to know that the dimensions of the cavities in the hydroquinone lattice $(\approx \pu{10 \mathring{A}})$ correspond closely with the size of buckminsterfullerene $(\ce{C_{60}})$, which forms a very high symmetry 3:1 structure, $\ce{3(C6H4(OH)2)}.\ce{C_{60}}$, with hydroquinone, a full occupancy of each cage, $x = 1$  Furthermore, the interplane distance between the  $\ce{C_{60}}$ surface and hydroquinone aryl ring is $\pu{3.1 \mathring{A}}$, suggesting optimum $\pi$-$\pi$ stacking (Ref. 1).
About the structure of hydroquinone-$\ce{SO2}$ clathrate, an earlier report (Ref. 2) states that:

A detailed determination, mainly by three-dimensional Furrier methods, has shown that hydroquinone molecules link together through hydrogen bonding to form infinite three-dimensional complexes of trigonal symmetry. The resulting giant molecule has a form, imposed by the dimension of hydroquinone molecule and the disposition of hydrogen bonds, so open that two such giant molecules are built up completely interpenetrating each other but having no direct attachment. In cavities enclosed simultaneously by the two giant molecules are located the molecules of the second volatile component which cannot escape from its surrounding. The composition $\ce{3C6H4(OH)2.M}$ is determined by the number of speces available for the second molecule $\ce{M}$. For the case where $\ce{M}$ is sulphur dioxide the co-ordinates of all atoms of the hydroquinone framework have been found. The position of the sulphur dioxide and its rotation about one axis have also been established by Furrier analysis. In the hydroquinone molecule interatomic distances found (to within about $\pm \pu{0.03 \mathring{A}}$) are $\ce{C-C} \ 1.39,$ $\ce{C-O} \ 1.36,$ $\ce{OH...O} \ \pu{2.75 \mathring{A}}$. The hydroxy groups are arranged in hydrogen-bonded hexagons.

Note: I chnged the the word quinol given in above except to hydroquinone for the consistence in this post.
The schematic representation of hydrogen-bonded hexagon is shown below:

A X-ray crystallographic study of methanol enclathrated in the β-hydroquinone lattice, which is closely related to  $\ce{SO2}$-trapped in the β-hydroquinone is published later (Ref. 3):

The crystal structure of a $\beta$-hydroquinone–methanol clathrate, $\ce{3C6H4(OH)2·xCH3OH}$ $(x= 0.887)$, has been determined. The encaged $\ce{CH3OH}$ molecule has three preferred orientations related by three-fold rotation about the $c$ axis. In each orientation, the $\ce{C–O}$ bond is tilted by 35° from $c$ to facilitate interaction of the hydroxy-group with three phenolic oxygen atoms of a neighbouring $\ce{[OH]6}$ ring. Crystals are rhombohedral, space group $R3$, with $Z= 3$ in a hexagonal unit cell of dimensions $a= 16.621 (2), \ c= \pu{5.562(1) \mathring{A}}$. Refinement of $632$ observed data yielded $R \ 0.043$.

Some facts about $\ce{3C6H4(OH)2·xSO2}$:

It has been known since 1859 (Ref. 2).
The crystals of $\ce{3C6H4(OH)2·xSO2}$ is yellow colored and only the colored clathrate of hydroquinone known for long time until as recently as 1979 (Ref. 4).
The above fact is somewhat surprising since the available crystallographic and spectroscopic data (Ref.2 & 5) reveal a remarkably small interaction of $\ce{SO2}$ and hydroquinone in the clathrate. Based on their studies on Raman and electronic absorption spectroscopy of the clathrate, Ref. 4 suggested that a charge transfer complex is formed between $\ce{SO2}$ and hydroquinone.

For more crystallographic data, read Ref. 2 & 5 as well.
References:

Jonathan W. Steed and Jerry L. Atwood, "Chapter 7.7. Hydroquinone, Phenols, Dianin's Compound, and the Hexahost Strategy," In Supramolecular Chemistry, Third Edition; John Wiley & Sons Ltd: Chichester, West Sussex, United Kingdom, 2022, pp. 501-502 (ISBN: 978-111958251-9).
D. E. Palin and H. M. Powell, "50. The structure of molecular compounds. Part III. Crystal structure of addition complexes of quinol with certain volatile compounds," J. Chem. Soc. 1947, 208-221 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1039/JR9470000208).
Thomas C. W. Mak, "Orientation of methanol enclathrated in the β-hydroquinone lattice: an X-ray crystallographic study," J. Chem. Soc., Perkin Trans. 2 1982, (11), 1435-1437 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1039/P29820001435).
P.S. Santos and P.C. Isolani, "The pre-resonance raman effect of the $\ce{SO2}$ clathrate of hydroquinone," Chemical Physics Letters 1979, 67(2-3),  487-490 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/0009-2614(79)85211-2).
J. E. D. Davies, "Clathrates and inclusion compounds. Part I. Infrared and Raman studies of several β-quinol (hydroquinone) clathrates," J. Chem. Soc., Dalton Trans. 1972, (11), 1182-1188 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1039/DT9720001182).
The ref. 67 mentioned in except of Ref. 1 is: Motosuke Naoki, Takashi Yoshizawa, Nobuaki Fukushima, Motonari Ogiso, and Masaki Yoshino, "A New Phase of Hydroquinone and Its Thermodynamic Properties," J. Phys. Chem. B 1999, 103(30), 6309–6313 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/jp990480k).

